# Is there a library/tool I can use to do a google like search inside a non public web application?

Tags: .net, web

I am working on .NET based web application. This web application is not publicly available. However, I want to know if it is possible to use a library with a modern google like search algorithm to search for data in the web application. Is there a nice library/tool I can use? The pages are not publicly available. It would be nice to have something this:

https://www.google.com/cse/

but for a non public web application.

Comment: you can use (for instance) [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org) - if i correctly understood your question..

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want the search to work.

The basic way is to do full-text search is your SQL base, if text is what you want to search.

If you want a more advanced search capability, should probably be running Solr/Elasticsearch. I prefer Elasticsearch myself. You can either host this yourself (on a VM/in an Azure worker role), or buy it as SaaS from one of the companies that provides Elasticsearch SaaS.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend very powerful search engine I used a while back for an intranet project based on ASP.NET. It may be a bit intimidating at first due to sheer number of features (which are all great), but in the end may be easier to implement than Lucene.NET or similar solutions.

http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/index.html

It offers search results sorted by relevance or date, wildcard searching, exact phrase matching, "Google-like" context results, highlighting, spelling suggestions, synonyms, graphical statistic reports, international language support, incremental indexing, images and thumbnails, content filtering, XML/RSS OpenSearch output, Stemming options to provide more accurate results, native ASP.NET server control, powerful Custom Meta Fields feature for database-like search criterias and more.